# Read annotations using Apache Bcel library

Tags: java, annotations, bcel

I'm trying to read class annotations using this code:

```
JavaClass jclas = new ClassParser("src\\test\\org\\poc\\TargetHello.class").parse();

        ClassGen cg = new ClassGen(jclas);

        Attribute[] attributes = cg.getAttributes();

        for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
            if (attribute instanceof Annotations) {
                Annotations annotations = (Annotations) attribute;
                AnnotationEntry[] entries= annotations.getAnnotationEntries();
            }
        }
```

But for this code `attribute instanceof Annotations` I get error: `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.Attribute' to 'org.apache.bcel.classfile.Annotations'`

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  You didn't give a complete compilable example nor say what commands you ran.  Here is what I did.

File `Hello.java`:

```java
@Deprecated
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

File `AttributeAnnotations.java`:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.AnnotationEntry;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Annotations;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Attribute;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.ClassGen;

public class AttributeAnnotations {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JavaClass jclas = new ClassParser("Hello.class").parse();

    ClassGen cg = new ClassGen(jclas);

    Attribute[] attributes = cg.getAttributes();

    for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
      System.out.println("attribute: " + attribute);
      if (attribute instanceof Annotations) {
        Annotations annotations = (Annotations) attribute;
        System.out.println("annotations: " + annotations);
        AnnotationEntry[] entries = annotations.getAnnotationEntries();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Commands to run:

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/bcel/bcel/6.4.1/bcel-6.4.1.jar
javac Hello.java
javac -cp bcel-6.4.1.jar AttributeAnnotations.java
java -cp .:bcel-6.4.1.jar AttributeAnnotations
```

All the commands complete without errors.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me how to print the name of the annotation only and get some particular key when we have a String key and array for values?

Comment: Without a concrete test case, and without knowing [what you have tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), it's hard to give an answer.  It's also off-topic to this question.  Could you open another question with a full test case and what you have tried?